# 2 id column after JOIN in Laravel. How to access to both IDs in Controller and Blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

After join I got table with 2 ID column. Now I don't know how to access in Controller and Blade both of IDs.

In Blade when I try `{{$value->id}}` and it gets second ID.

```
$users = User::where('user_id', $user_id)
->join('tagged', 'tagged.taggable_id', '=', 'users.id')
->orderBy('users.id', 'asc')
->get();
```

Gives me:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | name| phone | id | taggable_type | taggable_id |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I get both IDs in Controller and Blade?

Comment: Add a `select` clause to your query. [check the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects)

Comment: @JiFus Thanks for your answer. 

I used `select`, but result gets limited. I need all data from join table. 
I can access any other data from this table. But I can't access to first ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $users = DB::table('users')->where('user_id','=', $user_id)
  ->select('users.*','tagged.id as tagged_id') //add fields required from tagged table in this row
  ->join('tagged', 'tagged.taggable_id', '=', 'users.id')
  ->orderBy('users.id', 'asc')
  ->get();

  Use $users->tagged_id and $users->id in view
```